# Datatable Column <Column name>is readonly.Error while updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a datatable.There i have column name "TotalCases".When i am trying to update the row its getting an error "Column TotalCases is readonly".I have set ReadOnly=false.Still i am getting this error

```
DataTable dtStock = new DataTable();
DataColumn dcTotalCases = new DataColumn("TotalCases");
dcTotalCases.ReadOnly = false;
dtStock.Columns.Add(dcTotalCases);

  DataRow drStock = dtStock.Rows.Find(Datakey);
  drStock["TotalCases"] = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)item.FindControl("txtOrderCases")).Text;
```

I am tring to retain values in the textbox of template column in the grid.I am trying the follwing link [Link](http://www.ilearnttoday.com/c-aspnet-gridview-how-to-keep-modified-data-of-template-fields-when-paging-is-enabled)

Comment: 1. Column doesnt hold rows. 2. what is `drStock`? 3. What are you trying to do -write more details

Comment: yes this columns doesn'thold rows.. Post more info...

Answer (score 0):

I think `drStock["TotalCases"]` is read-only. In other words, this indexer property is read-only, and the column is not read-only. Maybe you should try another syntax. I'll check it out and update my answer.

This code works for me:

```
DataTable dtStock = new DataTable();
DataColumn dcTotalCases = new DataColumn("TotalCases");
dcTotalCases.ReadOnly = false;
dtStock.Columns.Add(dcTotalCases);
DataRow drStock = dtStock.NewRow();
drStock["TotalCases"] = "something";
dtStock.Rows.Add(drStock);
```

First you should create a DataRow with the same schema using `NewRow()` method. Then you should assign the value to it, and it works just fine. Then you should add the newly created row to the table.

Comment: I have tried to retain value in the grid..."http://www.ilearnttoday.com/c-aspnet-gridview-how-to-keep-modified-data-of-template-fields-when-paging-is-enabled"

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some rows to the table before trying to find and then update a row. I'd also check your row is not `NULL` before you attempt update it.